# Use public repo privately but receive updates from the master public repo

Tags: github, repository

I would like to extend existing public repo and store privately for private research purpose but still somehow receive updates from a public repo.

I'm not familiar with fork/clones. How can I make this work?

Comment: Become familiar with forks.

Comment: @chepner its not fork.

Answer (score 0):

Mirror the master repo. Not fork.